# TYPO3 new record appearing on wrong location in Backend List

Tags: typo3, backend, extbase

I'm developing a new extension using ExtBase in TYPO3 (4.7) for a client.

I have however the strangest problem. In the back-end, my  possible, new record types are - as usual - listed in the Insert new record Backend List. Usually each of these record-types are preceded by the module name (actually they are grouped right after the module name).. However, in my case, 1 or 2 of the record-types of any other extension appear within my extension's list as well.. I've been trying to figure out pretty much all that I can, I even copied the extension over to an entirely different TYPO3 installation, but the same problem persists..

If of any extension some records appear just below my extension's title, and I delete that particular extension, just some other record-types appear of another extension.

What's going on here??

[image]

Comment: Can you post your TCA configuration for your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Short & late answer:

i guess you have defined the title of your models in two different ways or with a non-existent languagefile in your ext_tables.php. Something like this:

Model1:

```
$TCA['tx_aaext_domain_model_one'] = array(
'ctrl' => array(
    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:bn_news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xml:tx_bnnews_domain_model_categories',
```

Model2:

```
$TCA['tx_aaext_domain_model_two'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'Static Title',
```

and/or your extension-name has an underscore like aa_extension, then this error can happen.
Make sure that both title-definitions are dynamic and begin with "LLL:EXT:" and point to an existing translation. Everything should be fine now.

Long answer will be to long :)